# собрать данные из динамической таблицы html в json на чистом js

Tags: javascript, html, json, таблицы

нужна помощь в сборе данных из таблицы, у меня меня есть динамическая таблица которая добавляет строку из выбранного пункта в теге `<select>`, строка создается со следующими параметрами

```
function addRow(selectAnswer) {
 const empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
 let rowCnt = empTab.rows.length;
 let tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt); 
 for (let c = 0; c < HeaderTable.length; c++) {
  let td = document.createElement('td'); 
  td = tr.insertCell(c);
  if (c == 0) {
   let button = document.createElement('button');
   button.textContent = "Удалить";
   button.setAttribute('id', selectAnswer);
   button.setAttribute("class", "clearBtn")
   button.setAttribute("onclick", "addSelect(this)")
   td.appendChild(button);
} else if (c == 1) {
   let ele = document.createElement('span');
   ele.textContent = selectAnswer
   td.appendChild(ele);
} else {
   let ele1 = document.createElement("input");
   ele1.setAttribute("type", "number")
   td.appendChild(ele1)
  };
 }
}
```

при нажатие на кнопку Расчет каждая строка должна собраться в JSON и отправиться дальше,

я собираю данные следующим образом

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
 let database = []
 const table = document.getElementById("empTable")
  for (let i = 1; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   database.push({ name: row.cells[1], massa: row.cells[2], W: row.cells[3], A: row.cells[4] })
 }
     console.log(database)
     calck(database)
 })
```

в результате получаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но я не могу понять как мне собрать название из `span` и все значения из `input` , а не ячейки (`td`) из таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот корректный код для сбора данных

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let database = [];
  const table = document.getElementById("empTable");
  for (let i = 1; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
    database.push({
      name: row.cells[1].innerText, // Простой текст внутри ячейки или дочернем span
      massa: row.cells[2].querySelector('input').value, // Значение input в ячейке
      W: row.cells[3].querySelector('input').value, // Значение input в ячейке
      A: row.cells[4].querySelector('input').value // Значение input в ячейке
    });
  }
  console.log(database);
  calck(database);
});
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, оказалось всё проще чем я думал)